# How should I find cycle in the directed graph and list out the nodes which are forming the cycle?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have the array of objects in javascript i am trying to draw the directed graph how should i find whether it contains cycle or not if contains what are the elements forming the cycle
Graph is not strongly connected and nodes can be isolated like "f"

```
 array = {};
//operations   parents
    array[a] = [b,c]
    array[b] = [d,c]
    array[e] = [a,b]
    array[d] = [e]
    array[f] = []
```

[image: considering the above data- assume keys as child and values as parents made a directed graph which looks like this]

I want to find the cycle between the operations like here we have cycle from e-d-b-e?
How should i find the cycle? I am using javascript.

Comment: if you run a dfs on this graph and if you reach at the same node from where you started at some point, congrats you have found a cycle in any graph :p

Comment: What are the `a`, `b`, `c`, ... variables in your script, and is that all you have?

Comment: a,b,c are not variables they are the values these are a javascript object as (key,Values)

Comment: If they are not variables, then that is not valid JavaScript. Valid literal values are numbers, strings (they must be quoted), booleans, `null` or `undefined`. `a` is none of those.

Comment: @trincot that's why I have assumed some values for a,b,c,d,e to show  how the algorithm would basically work ....

Comment: It would be more useful if you would present code that is valid though.

Comment: Do you need just one cycle, and if so, can it be any cycle, or do you then want to have the shortest or longest?

Comment: @trincot I need to find the first cycle that came print the nodes also which form the cycle, also my graph is not strongly connected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a BFS solution that will find one cycle (if there are any), which will be (one of) the shortest one(s).

```js
function getCycle(graph) {
    // Copy the graph, converting all node references to String
    graph = Object.assign(...Object.keys(graph).map( node =>
                ({ [node]: graph[node].map(String) }) 
    ));

    let queue = Object.keys(graph).map( node => [node] );
    while (queue.length) {
        const batch = [];
        for (const path of queue) {
            const parents = graph[path[0]] || [];
            for (const node of parents) {
                if (node === path[path.length-1]) return [node, ...path];
                batch.push([node, ...path]);
            }
        }
        queue = batch;
    }
}

// First example
var graph = {
    a: ['b', 'c'],
    b: ['d', 'c'],
    e: ['a', 'b'],
    d: ['e']
};
var result = getCycle(graph);
console.log(result);

// Second example (numeric node references)
var graph = {
    0: [4],
    1: [4,0],
    2: [0,1],
    3: [1],
    4: [3]
};
var result = getCycle(graph);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

NB: If you define your graph with number references, a type conversion is needed since object properties are always of type string. We could use `==` instead of `===`, but then the output will still be a mix of string and numbers; I think it is nicer to first convert every node reference to string.

Comment: solution works for the strongly connected graph but not able to find the cycle in the where vertex few vertex is not reachable from a point.   Fails in this scenario      
 var graph = {};
graph[0] = [4];
graph[1] = [4,0];
graph[2] = [0,1];
graph[4] = [3];
graph[3] = [1];

Comment: The reason it fails for your example is that the node references are numbers, while the keys of the graph object are strings (as always in JS). I have adapted the code to deal with this (I had deleted it temporarily between updates).

Answer (score 0):

Depth-First Search. If DFS finds an edge that points to an already discovered ancestor of the current node, the graph contains a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

So as I commented, you need to basically traverse through the whole graph and keep a visited array to keep track of nodes that you have visited till now and if you reach any already visited node, then there exists a cycle in the provided directed graph.

To make your work easier here is a running code, you can use it as reference to build your algorithm on it.

Improved my answer little bit, iterating through all nodes, so that it covers some unreachable paths as well. Thank you all :)

```
array = {};

/*
Assuming 
a = 0
b=  1
c = 2
d = 3
e = 4
*/

// Here I am forming an adjacency list of directed nodes based on the diagram
array[0] = [4];
array[1] = [4,0];
array[2] = [0,1];
array[4] = [3];
array[3] = [1];
visited = {};
visited[0] = 0;
visited[1] = 0;
visited[2] = 0;
visited[3] = 0;
visited[4] = 0;

list_for_cycle_nodes = [];

for(var node = 0; node<5; node++) {
   if (dfs(node)) {
    for (var index = 0; index < list_for_cycle_nodes.length; index++) {
      console.log(list_for_cycle_nodes[index]+" ");
    }
    console.log('There is a cycle');
  } else {
    console.log('Yipee, there is no cycle');
  } 
}

function dfs(s) {
  if(visited[s] == 1) {
    return true;
  }
  list_for_cycle_nodes.push(s);
  visited[s] = 1;
  var flag = false;
  if(array[s].length <= 0) {
    return false;
  }
  for(var index = 0; index<array[s].length; index++) {
    flag = flag | dfs(array[s][index]);
    if(flag) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return flag;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank's zen!Your solution is perfect and works fine but I need to find the elements who are forming the cycle - like in your case it will be 4-1-3

Comment: ohh but your question said something else, it just asked to find a cycle

Comment: But once you understand the concept of dfs, then it wouldn't be a much problem to find the chain of nodes that are forming the cycle

Comment: "if contains what are the elements forming the cycle" Sure, i look into that! Appreciated your solution

Comment: Your algorithm is actually wrong. First of all, it fails to find anything that is not reachable from first vertex, second it finds a loop in a graph 0->1, 0->2, 1->3, 2->3, which does not contain a loop.

Comment: Ya I agree I need to call dfs on all the nodes in order for it to find a cycle that could start from each node. That will fix it

Comment: But I coded this thing in like 5 mins just to get him started and he could take from there on

Comment: @AyushRawat please add edit the problem to add the part about printing

Answer (score 0):

After referring to the comments on @zenwraigts solution I infer that this is a problem of [Strongly Connected Components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component). You can find a good tutorial [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strongly-connected-components/), you can find javascript implementations [here](https://gist.github.com/chadhutchins/1440602) and [here](https://github.com/mikolalysenko/strongly-connected-components).

How is this a problem of SCC ?

all vertices which form a strongly connected component for a cycle, the problem reduces to finding all SCC's and print them